# Why jquery nth child give inconsistent result when apply to ul and li

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a container with a group of `ul`s, of each have 4 `li`s.
I created the first `ul` then copy the rest by Javascript.

When I call to find nth-child of all `ul`s, eg `$("ul:nth-child(1)")`, it return nothing, the first `ul` item appear with `$("ul:nth-child(2)")` (n is starting from 2)

But when I try to do the same for `li` inside an `ul`, the first `li` item is appearing with `$("ul li:nth-child(1)")` (n is starting from 1)

I am developing in jQuery 1.11.1 but the fiddle give the same result when using 1.11.0 (because they don't have 1.11.1 yet from the menu)

Am I missing something or is it a bug in jQuery?

Reference: 
Tested in Chrome 40.0.2214.93 m under Windows 7 Enterprise/English

This is the [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/simongcc/Lv6wawh8/)

Edited: (more precise desire)
I don't mean to find `li` because I know how to find exactly which `li` and what li with ">" while I mean even using the same algorithm for ul elements and for li elements, it gave different results.

I want to find the (2n-1) ul within all ul using nth-child but it give the wrong result. I have to use (3n-1) instead to find every other 3 ul because the starting element beginning 1 more than it is expected.

(based on the example above, the retrieve every 3 `ul` element)

```
start from first `ul` element amongst 15 `ul`s (skip every 3 ul element)
the first ul element in the set $(".keywords ul:nth-child(1)") 
give nothing (not as expected)
eg. $(".keywords ul:nth-child(3n-1)"), when n = 1, first element is 2, the starting element in the set is 2.
```

**Why there is 1 more element cascaded?**

(using only the first list to test for retrieving every 3 `li` element)

```
$(".keywords ul:eq(0) li:nth-child(2n-1)")
the first li element in the set $(".keywords ul:eq(0) li:nth-child(1)") 
give the first element.(as expected) when n = 1, first element is 1, as expected.
```

So, the skipping seems different for specified ul and li in the example.
While I can still do the desired result, when apply to `ul`, it is cascaded 1 element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ul:nth-child` has a different meaning than `li:nth-child`.  In the first case, you are looking for a `ul` element that is the nth child of its parent. In the second, you are looking for the nth `li` inside a list.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the concept. I just use it intuitively without grasping its definition. Definition is `"Selects all elements that are the nth-child of their parent."` So, in my example, `h1` is also being considered when it is being searched.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a descendant selector

```
$(".main-area .list-container .keywords ul > li:nth-child(1)").length
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/x2fodL8n/)

Your selector, tries to find a `ul` which is inside `.main-area .list-container .keywords` and is a first child element of its parent.

Comment: I want to find the (2n-1) ul within all `ul` using nth-child but it give the wrong result. I have to use (3n-1) instead to find every other 3 ul because the starting element beginning 1 more than it is expected. In this case, how to achieve?

Comment: @simongcc I don't think you can use `nth-child` for that, in the attached demo with are the `ul`s you want to select